# Receiving a "TypeError: 'int' object is not callable" error when finding Primes?

Tags: python, object, integer, callable

I'm trying to write a program to find prime numbers, here's my code so far

```
import math
import numpy 
PrimeList = (2)    #starting prime list at 2
for numbers in range(3,10001):    #beginning loop for primes from 3 to 10000
    i = 0
    PrimeList_flag = True
    while PrimeList(i) <= math.floor(math.sqrt(numbers)):    # checks number divisibility by any prime less than or equal to sqrt of number
        if numbers % prime(i)==0:
            PrimeList_flag = False    # sets flag to true if the last note is true
            break    #loop breaker
        i += 1   # for i greater than or equal to 1
    if PrimeList_flag ==True: 
        PrimeList.append(num)
print(PrimeList)
```

which returns this error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-304e050286f5> in <module>
      5     j = 0
      6     PrimeList_flag = True
----> 7     while PrimeList(j) <= math.floor(math.sqrt(numbers)):    # checks number divisibility by any prime less than or equal to sqrt of number
      8         if numbers % prime(j)==0:
      9             PrimeList_flag = False    # sets flag to true if the last note is true

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

I've checked other answers relating to this regarding the assignment of a variable to an integer in prior lines of code, but I'm not seeing that in any code I've written thus far. Is there something else I'm missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "TypeError: 'int' object is not callable" What do you expect `PrimeList(i)` to mean? "I've checked other answers relating to this regarding the assignment of a variable to an integer in prior lines of code" What do you expect `PrimeList = (2)` to mean?

Comment: `PrimeList = (2)` should be `PrimeList = [2]`

Comment: If these aren't simple typos, then you have one or more fundamental misunderstandings which should be addressed by following a tutorial, not by trying to come up with your own projects and getting help on them.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, lists in python are declared with square brackets - what you have is a simple integer.

Second of all, and the answer to your specific questin, you have to use square brackets for indexing. Parentheses are used for calling callable objects (functions). So you would need to use

```
PrimeList[i]
```

Also, where did `prime` come from? Is that a function you imported?

Comment: Actually, `(2)` is **not** a tuple; it's just the integer `2`. A comma is required to make a tuple, like `(2,)`.

Comment: Thank you, @gshpychka and Karl, the problem was lack of brackets. Karl, you're right, I do need to spend more time understanding the fundamentals. gshpychka, ```prime``` should've been ```PrimeList```.

Comment: If you feel that the above answer answers your question, consider accepting it.